# Prevent GNU Make from generating protobuf code each build

Tags: c++, protocol-buffers, gnu-make

I have below Makefile which runs Google's `protoc` on some `proto` files, generate the code and build the library
Everything works fine except the fact that it generates code every `make` run, despite there were no changes to the `proto` files or whatever. How do I prevent that?

```
GEN_FLAG:=$(PROJECT_ROOT)/build/.etcd_protocols_gen

ETCD=$(PROJECT_ROOT)/ext/etcd/
PROTOCOLS=$(ETCD)proto/

PROTO_FILES=$(shell find $(PROTOCOLS) -name \*.proto)
FILES=$(wildcard *.cc)
OBJS=$(patsubst %.cc,%.o,$(FILES))
LIB=$(BUILD_LIB_DIR)/libetcdclient.so

DIRS=proto

.PHONY: all
all: etcd-gen $(LIB)

-include $(FILES:.cc=.d)

.PHONY: etcd-gen
etcd-gen:
    $(Q)echo "Generating ETCD gRPC C++ sources"
    @ln -sf $(PROTOBUF_DIR)/libprotoc.so.16.0.0 $(PROTOBUF_DIR)/libprotoc.so.16
    @ln -sf $(PROTOBUF_DIR)/libprotobuf.so.16.0.0 $(PROTOBUF_DIR)/libprotobuf.so.16
    @LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(PROTOBUF_DIR) $(PROTOBUF_DIR)/protoc -I $(PROTOCOLS) --cpp_out=. $(PROTO_FILES)
    @LD_LIBRARY_PATH=$(PROTOBUF_DIR) $(PROTOBUF_DIR)/protoc -I $(PROTOCOLS) --grpc_out=. --plugin=protoc-gen-grpc=$(PROJECT_ROOT)/ext/grpc/bin/grpc_cpp_plugin $(PROTO_FILES)
    @touch $(GEN_FLAG)

%.o: %.cc
    @echo "CC $<"
    $(Q)$(CC) $(CFLAGS) -c -o $@ $< -ldl
    $(Q)$(CC) -MM $(CFLAGS) -MF $*.d -MT $*.o $*.cc

$(LIB): $(OBJS)
    @echo "LD $@"
    $(Q)$(CXX) $(CXXFLAGS) -shared -Wl,-soname,$(notdir $(LIB)) -o $(LIB) $(OBJS) $(LFLAGS) -L$(PROTOBUF_DIR) -l:libprotobuf.so.16

clean:
    $(Q)rm -f *.d *.o *.pb.cc *.pb.h
    $(Q)rm -f $(BUILD_LIB_DIR)/libetcdclient.so
    $(Q)rm -f GEN_FLAG
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`make` considers the target to be the file to be generated. Any comparison of timestamps to determine whether or not to rebuild that file is therefore a comparison of those of the dependencies versus that of the target.

In your case make is checking the timestamp of a non-existing file `etcd-gen`, and since it doesn't exist or bears no relationship to the sources anyway (the sources aren't listed as dependencies) a rebuild is triggered each time.

What you could do instead is re-structure your makefile so your `proto` sources are dependencies of the `$(GEN_FLAG)` *and* the contents of `$(GEN_FLAG)` is a target. Then you can declare `$(GEN_FLAG)` a dependency of `etcd-gen`.

Comment: Actually, `etcd-gen` is correctly marked as a [phony target](https://www.gnu.org/software/make/manual/html_node/Phony-Targets.html) and its rule is invoked every time withoud looking for a file, but you are of course right about the result.